# What's the difference between inputUser and inputPeerUser?

Tags: telegram-api

What's the difference between [inputUser](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/inputUser) and [inputPeerUser](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/inputPeerUser)?
They both have only `id` and `access_hash`.